# Open Source OLAP Framework for Java?

Tags: java, mdx, olap, rolap

I have been using [NReco](https://www.nrecosite.com/pivot_data_library_net.aspx) which provides "C# in-memory OLAP cube for fast data aggregation and pivot reports generation" for a little while now.

The goal now is to port the application to Java. What I am looking for is to:

1. Add an OLAP layer on top of PostgreSQL so that I can build cubes out of flattened data and
2. Query the OLAP cube with MDX via my own RESTful API

What do you recommend?

Comment: why don't use PivotData microservice (based on PivotData library you mentioned) for the same purposes? This is .NET Core app that can be hosted Linux, simple web API can be consumed both from front-end (javascript) and java backend.